# Image hover and link combo

Tags: html, css, hover

I created an image over with the code below but I need to add a link to it that open in a new tab on clicking the image. I've tried searching through other posts but I can't find this exact combination of both 'image hover' and 'link'. I'd appreciate the help.

Here's the hover code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html > 
<head> 
<style type="text/css"> 
.pic{ 
      width:16px; 
      height:16px; 
      opacity: 1; 
      filter: alpha(opacity=100); 
      background: url(http://i.picresize.com/images/2014/10/12/QmCgI.png) no-repeat;
} 
.pic:hover 
{ 
      opacity: 0.3; 
      filter: alpha(opacity=30); } 
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
      <div class="pic">
      </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: why not just use an <a target="_blank" class="pic" href="..."> instead of a div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add hover through CSS class.
For new link to open through clicking on image (in new tab) use the following:

```
<img src="your image path" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com')"/>random text
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/yertc4d9/) Added a link around the image, and the `target="blank"` attribute forces the link to open in a new tab

Answer (score 0):

**Eureka!!!**
After toiling I finally made a crude (to put it rightly) code that functions. I took a text link I created earlier, added the image I wanted to 'src', placed both html codes on an editor and started adding and removing until both hover and link got synced. Here's the final code below in case someone else finds it useful or to make it better. I'm a beginner coder so I'm pretty excited about this. Thanks everyone for your answers. Long live Coding!! :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html > 
<head> 
<style type="text/css"> 
.pic{ 
      width:15px; 
      height:15px; 
      opacity: 1; 
      filter: alpha(opacity=100); 
      background: url(//i.picresize.com/images/2014/10/12/QmCgI.png) no-repeat;
} 
.pic:hover 
{ 
      opacity: 0.3; 
      filter: alpha(opacity=30); } 
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
      <div class="pic" 
      </div> 

 <style type="text/css" media="screen" />
</style> 

</head>
<body>

<p><b><a href="myfile.htm"><img src="//i.picresize.com/images/2014/10/12/QmCgI.png"></a></b></p>

</body>
</html>
```